# Installing xserver-xorg-input-wacom

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gimp, apt-get

I'm trying to get my wacom tablet (CTL-490) working with my current Ubuntu installation (14.04). I'm following the guide at http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Xf86-input-wacom and I'm getting errors while running `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-wacom`.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-input-wacom : Depends: xorg-input-abi-20
                            Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.14.99.902)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So far, I am able to get the tablet to move the pointer, and pressure sensitivity is working with GIMP and Krita, but I am unable to map to displays (I have to do it through xsetwacom), and there are no tablets detected in System Settings > Wacom Tablet. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tablet shouldn't require updating the Wacom X Driver, which should ship with Ubuntu. While helping another user[1] with 14.04.04 I found that no tablets were supported in the control panel on this point 4 release.

If you're also running 14.04.04, you might want to file a bug with Ubuntu.

[1] https://askubuntu.com/questions/746858/wacom-tablet-gui-no-tablet-detected/746868#746868